# How to catch SSH command output contain sub string ? - Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ssh, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to catch the output of the command and throw error/success accordingly.

```
$resultFromServer = []; 
SSH::run($command, function($line)
{
    echo $line.PHP_EOL;

    if($line!= null) {
        array_push($resultFromServer, $line); // crash 
    }
});

dd($resultFromServer);
```

Check out my output

```
WARNING: Kubernetes configuration file is group-readable. This is insecure. Location: /root/.kube/config WARNING: Kubernetes configuration file is world-readable. This is insecure. Location: /root/.kube/config Error: open test.yaml: no such file or directory

[]
```

I'm trying to look for this **string** `Error:` and whatever to the right of it, I will display in my alert message.

> Error: open test.yaml: no such file or directory

## I'm trying

to store each line into an array and loop through and check for string contain, but I can't even store it into the array.

I kept getting a crash - ***if*** - I uncomment that line

[image]

How do I prevent the crash ? Do I need to add some sleep() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because SSH::run uses a closure, `$resultFromServer` does not exist within the scope of the sub function. You need to pass it in with the `use` keyword as well as pass it in as a reference since you're modifying it on the inside:

```
SSH::run($command, function($line) use (&$resultFromServer)
{
    echo $line.PHP_EOL;

    if($line!= null) {
        array_push($resultFromServer, $line); // crash 
    }
});
```